# Initialization step in EM algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I am trying to understand how EM  algorithm works, and I am referring to these [referencess](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25111/how-does-expectation-maximization-work), [research paper](http://ai.stanford.edu/~chuongdo/papers/em_tutorial.pdf).

[image]

I understand what is going on here, We take random THETA(a), THETA(b) and for each coin toss, we compute P(coin a), P(coin b) and recompute THETA(a), THETA(b).

What I am not able to understand is reasoning behind initial theta values. What if I take same value for both theta values at the beginning? In that case, theta for both of the coins will always be the same?

Comment: Better initialization usually results in faster convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Well, think of the interpretation of equal `THETAs`. If `THETA(a) = THETA(b)`, you're basically saying that probabilities for two coins are exactly the same, so it's not important which coin was it. If you're assuming equal probabilities you can say that there was only one coin.